# Using loadDelta feature in Dropbox IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox

I am using dropbox to upload and download files. I want to be able to be notified when a file changes in a certain folder (or if not possible in the entire dropbox account) so that the user is advised. I don't seem to find any way to do it apart from using the delta feature. I found this code:

```
-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedDeltaEntries:(NSArray *)entries reset:(BOOL)shouldReset cursor:(NSString *)cursor hasMore:(BOOL)hasMore{
for (DBDeltaEntry *file in entries) {
     if(!file.metadata.isDirectory){
         NSLog(@"File: %@ ", file.metadata.filename );
     }else {
         NSLog(@"Directory: %@  ", file.metadata.filename );
     }
 }
}
```

....from this stack overflow question: [Using Delta in Dropbox API with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691367/using-delta-in-dropbox-api-with-ios)

But it gives errors. I found out there is a feature like:

```
[self.restClient loadDelta:NSString];
```

But I don't seem to find any examples, and please don't give me a link to the dropbox site which has no sample code at all.